How to update the child of a model based on a select option
My question might feel stupid but I got this model :

export interface Role {
  id: number;
  rolename: string;
  permissions: string;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
}

export interface User {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
  Role: Role;
}


And I want to create a form to update the role based on the list of roles I have.
I have tried this:
<label for="roleId" class="form-label">Role:</label>
<select name="" [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.Role" (change)="onRoleChange()">
    <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role">{{ role.rolename }}</option>
</select>


But I got an error : Object is possibly 'null'.ngtsc(2531)
I didn't find any good advice online, should I use a 2nd variable as 'selectedRole' and bind this value or should I create a child component to deal with it ?
I tried to change it to
<select name="" [(ngModel)]="selectedUser?.Role" (change)="onRoleChange()">
    <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role">{{ role.rolename }}</option>
</select>


Or change the model as

export interface Role {
  id: number;
  rolename: string;
  permissions: string;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
}

export interface User {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
  Role?: Role;
}


But it does not get any better.

Would you please provide more details on your code. How is onRoleChange() and selectedUser defined. Perhaps create a reproduceable example on https://stackblitz.com/

@T.Jami Thanks for the question
The (change)="onRoleChange()" does nothing, there is only a console.log to track the change.

how did you define selectedUser? apparently it is possible for selectedUser to be null, if thats the case, you need to handle it


When you define the selectedUser use
selectedUser:User={} as User


or, if you define like
selectedUser!:User

use a "if"
@if(selectedUser)
{
   ...
   <select name="" [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.Role" >
}



BTW: generally you only need store in the user the "role.id"

This does the job ! Thanks for the reply and thanks to @T.Jami too
